# Grok Pattern for multiline is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

```
        1st|                    2nd|3rd        |4th         |5th                 |6th              |7th          |8th   |2012.07.12 05:31:04      |10th  |ProductDir: C:\samplefiles\test\storage\4.0 (LF)
C:\samplefiles\test\storage\5.0 (LF)
SampleDir: (LF)
```

**Note: LF -> Line Feed** is getting appended

I have tried the following options.. Nothing seems to be working

1. `match => [ "message", "(?m)....`
2. `(?<message>(.|\r|\n)*)`
3. Greedydata is also not working as its not considering new line.
4. `mutate {gsub => ["message", "\n", "LINE_BREAK"] }`
5. ```
   codec => multiline { pattern => "^\s" negate => true what => previous }
   ```

Comment: Can you add which Elasticsearch and Logstash version that you use?

Comment: ELK version is 6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below one worked for me.

```
codec => multiline{
    pattern => "^\s*\d{1,}\|"
    negate => "true"
    what => "previous"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`(?m)%{GREEDYDATA}` will match any multiline log including yours.
Please test it [here](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: I tried this one but its not working. I think Line feed might be a problem

Comment: it works, when you copy/paste your log to grok debugger website make sure there is no new line after the pattern.

Comment: I have (LF) in my logs which comes up when last column data exceeds the limit

Comment: I mean, remove LF from debugger website from the pattern, not from the log.

Comment: In debugger website, It works fine but when I run through logstash in my local system, It causes the problem. Even with this (?<message>(.|\r|\n)*), It works in the website but not with logstash 6.3.0v